# Creating cross-compiled archive (static library) using CMake on Windows and relative path

Tags: windows, cmake, static-libraries, cross-compiling

Using CMake I'm able to cross-compile and create a static library which depends on other static libraries. However, the resulting static library doesn't include the "content" of the other static libraries. Therefore, I want to create an archive, i.e. a static library, that actually includes everything (all the object files).

To this aim, I've tried to use the following directive in CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(combined ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_AR} rc libcombined.a $<TARGET_FILE:target1> $<TARGET_FILE:target2> $<TARGET_FILE:target3>)
```

CMAKE_AR is set to an absolute path where my cross-compiler(archiver?) is; its values is something like: c:/arm/arm-none-eabi-ar.exe

However, when I try to build the project (make && make install), I receive the following error:

> '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/combined] Error 1

If I open the *build.make* file where the *src/CMakeFiles/combined* is, I have something similar to this:

```
src/CMakeFiles/combined:
    cd absolute-path-to-the-build-folder/src && ../../relative-path-to-the-archiver-executable/arm-none-eabi-ar.exe rc libcombined.a absolute-path-to-target1-archive absolute-path-to-target2-archive absolute-path-to-target3-archive
```

If I manually replace the relative path to the archiver executable with the absolute path, the new archive is created correctly. The same happens if I just add quotes in the specified archiver path.

At this point, I think it might be something related to Windows and/or to the make utility which doesn't interpret correctly the command/path.

Therefore, I have the following question:

- Why is the CMAKE_AR value converted to a relative path from an absolute path?
- How can I solve this without involving external scripts?

About last point, I tried to escape the CMAKE_AR path with quotes, but then I get the error: "COMMAND may not contain literal quotes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create an [object library](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library) that depends on your various static libraries in order to get a single library that contains all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, it doesn't resolve any include dependencies (as target_include_directories does with static libraries - not objects).

Comment: Are you using [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to specify your includes for the libraries?  That should propagate `INTERFACE` and `PUBLIC` include directories specified in the transitive dependencies.